# Charging LFP battery by continuous current or on/off - any difference with respect to lifetime?

Tags: battery-charging, pwm, lithium-ion

Does it make any difference with respect to lifetime of an LFP battery (48V, 120 Ah), whether the constant voltage stage during the charging cycle is achieved by just switching on/off the charging source intermittently (with a hysteresis, say, between 54.5 V and 55 V, just as an example), as opposed to reducing a continuous charging current until the voltage stays exactly constant? The charging source is supposed to have a current capacity < 1C, so that no overcurrent issues occur for the battery when switching it directly on.

My spontaneous reasoning would be that the on/off approach implies numerous small charge/discharge cycles, which eat up the lifetime of the battery, while the continuous current approach just keeps the voltage constant and, thus, is not lifetime relevant. Moreover, the voltage is even kept constant if an additional load is connected to the battery, at least if the current capacity of the charging source allows it.

But on the other hand, I could also reduce the on/off hysteresis more and more, and in the mathematical limit it becomes practically the same as a constant voltage. So, does the impact of the on/off approach simply depend on the chosen hysteresis? And as a small hysteresis means faster switching, will there be a separate effect on battery health coming from something like a "high frequency current strain"?

The on/off approach clearly requires less control and circuitry effort (no inductor, no flyback protection, no PID control design), so my hopes are that this is a recommended one. I actually don't know if this is done in any commercial product, hence I am asking.

Comment: Interesting question. The normal charge procedure recommended in datasheets are CV until current drops below a threshold and then terminate charge. Do you measure the current during the ON cycle?

Comment: I intend to do so, and be it only for informational purposes about solar panel yield. But the switching shall only be determined by voltage and the hysteresis settings.

Comment: Interesting side info: I had an additional cheap chinese charger (which sadly blew up after a few months because of improper thermal management, otherwise it seemed to work excellent). I can't remember that there were big inductors on the board. I wonder if that worked liked described in the question and if it strained my battery.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't apply pulsed/intermittent voltage to a Li-based battery.

Every time you apply a voltage (and therefore current) to a battery after a rest time, high-current-density spots may appear and these can cause excessive heat (locally) and/or unwanted chemical reactions (again, locally) which may eventually result in uneven charge distribution.

Other thing worth to mention is that the battery voltage can partially recover during the rest time. This can make the charging process less effective.

All in all, reduced performance and even reduced lifespan.

Comment: Have you got references about those claims? For example, why can the battery stand high current, but not high current after rest? Why do "chemical reactions" prefer after-rest over continuous charging. Can these effects be quantified and set into relation to each other? Not that I want to doubt you, but my impression is that there is a general lack of precise/scientific information about lithium chemistries, which is often being filled by hearsay, commercial storytelling and the like.

Comment: By the way, if the battery is externally loaded (like in a PV system with inverter connected), the battery does not stay at the saturation capacity for long. My inverter (with included charger) stops charging for the rest of the day if saturation voltage/threshold current is reached only once. This is pretty wasteful because 1) the available PV power is lost even though the battery is not full and 2) the battery is cycled even though it could be avoided. But it seems to be a necessary consequence of the recommended CCCV+threshold current charging algorithm.

Comment: @oliver I'm sure there are numerous researches about negative effects of intermittent charging (I/C). I can't provide any of them at the moment but I put here what I remember of I learnt from my professors and some other battery professionals I worked with in the past. On the other hand, there are some other researches ([this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S037877532031380X?via%3Dihub) and [this](http://www.electrochemsci.org/abstracts/vol16/210453.pdf)) proving that I/C can be beneficial but **when kept under control and applied with carefully-selected parameters**.

Comment: Thanks, Rohat, I will read the linked papers and see if I can come close to "selecting and controlling the parameters", and follow your advice otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the experimental [paper](http://www.electrochemsci.org/abstracts/vol16/210453.pdf) linked by Rohat Kilic somewhat contradicts the content of his answer. Apart from some reading in the coffee dregs, the apparent high sample scattering only permits the conclusion that effects on the cycle life (of LiCoO cells) are not significant. If at all, a certain caution with high switching frequencies (~1 kHz) is recommendable, but again, the unbiased eye may see it as reading the coffee dregs.

This is not to dispute any negative effects of pulsing on cycle life altogether, because it is clear that ohmic losses in the battery **will** increase when continuous current is replaced by a charge-equivalent pulse current, simply because its RMS value is higher and the ohmic losses scale as I^2*R. So, the question is not "if" but rather "to what extent" pulsing makes things worse.

The point is that using current pulsing is often seen from the perspective of allegedly improving battery charging performance, which is highly questionable, according to the literature. Therefore, a questionable improvement of charging connected with a possible deterioration of cycle life is not an attractive option.

However, seen from the perspective of enabling a much cheaper charger, there is a clear benefit (no inductor, no flyback protection, simpler circuitry...) in favor of charge pulsing.

If I have to pay 1000 € to buy a charger for a battery that cost me 2000 €, then I might accept up to ~30% deterioration with a simpler charger for 100 €, because the likelihood that I will reuse the expensive charger in 10 years when my battery fails, is negligible.